# How to prove these commutative maps are bijective

Tags: linear-algebra

I had asked a similar question here before in form of a proof verification, and I got the answer that my proof was correct, but as a result of a recent question I asked I have realized that my proof is wrong. We have two linear maps $f$ and $g$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f = 3 \cdot id$. How do we prove these functions are both isomorphisms i.e. bijective linear maps, given that $f \circ g = g \circ f = 3 \cdot id$?

What I initially tried was rewriting the $f \circ g = g \circ f = 3 \cdot id$ into a way that you'd get $id$ only on the RHS, but I'm not even sure what that proves. I also know that the identity mapping is bijective.

I'm given that if $f : X \to Y $ and $g : Y \to X$ are maps that satisfy $f \circ g = \text{id} _Y$ , then $f$ is surjective and $g$ is injective. If, moreover, $h: Y \to X$ is a map that satisfies $h \circ f = \text{id} _X$, then $f$ is also injective, and therefore bijective; we then have $g = h = f^{ - 1}$.

Comment: The idea is to prove that $f\circ g=n .Id$ imply that $f$ is surjective and $g$ injective. The other equality gives you the opposite, hence $f$ and$g$ are both injective and surjective : they are bijective

Comment: But how? $f \circ g = g \circ f = n \cdot id$, (in my particular case $n=3$), so $f \circ g$ can't equal $id$ right?

Comment: What I hinted in my comment would work even if the right hand side was an arbitrary bijection: if $f\circ g$ is bijective, then $f$ is surjective and $g$ injective

Comment: @Tryss How would one go about proving that? I know that the identity mapping is bijective, but that's it.

Comment: Try to show that if $f$ is not surjective, then $f\circ g$ is not surjective. Then that if $g$ is not injective, $f\circ g$ is not injective. Both are not hard, but you'll need to write clearly the definition of injectivity and surjectivity

Comment: @Tryss so you could basically say that because $id \cdot n$ is bijective, $f \circ g = g \circ f$ is bijective, thus $f$ and $g$ are bijective?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are on vector spaces. If the characteristic of the base field is  a divisor of n, take f=id, g = multiplication by n (=0). The result is obviously false.

(If the characteristic is prime to n, then Tryss comments give you the answer).

Comment: Indeed, didn't think about that... vector spaces over non zero characteristic fields are a little tricky ;)

Comment: This answer is a bit above my level

Comment: What is your base field?

Comment: @Heinrich I know what bijectivity is and the basics of vector spaces too. I also added something we were given which might make the proof easier but I haven't been able to figure it out for a long time now

Comment: I mean, you are talking about vector spaces over ... which field? If they are the rational numbers or real numbers, then forget my answer; you only need to follow Tryss suggestion. Take in mind that multiplication by n is then bijective (its inverse is multiplication by 1/n which is a rational and real number).

Comment: @Heinrich $n$ was $3$ in my case, so I guess rational/real. If I can prove that $id \cdot n$ is bijective, then can I simply state that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are bijective, and thus $g$ and $f$ are bijective?

Comment: Yes, reasoning as Tryss point you.